# Getting instance of started activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I a starting an Activity from a non-Activity class using the context. The Activity starts fine, but I need its instance immediately after the start up. Is there any way to the instance?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyApp.getAppContext(), MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MyApp.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);

Activity a = ???
doSomethingWithInstace(a);
```

Comment: no, and if you need this, then you should read http://d.android.com again

Comment: No, you are not able to do this, sorry. API doesnt provide solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `doSomethingWithInstance()` into your activity and call it from `onCreate()` or `onStart()`. Whatever data are needed your Activity can take them from the global `Application` object.